# Need help creating a 5 minute timer on my arduino arfter my humidity sensor goes below 60%

Tags: timer, arduino, sensors

I am making a device that automatically turns on my bathroom fan when I get in the shower. I need help setting a 5-minute timer at the end of my shower when it goes back below 60% humidity. I am not sure how to do this so I'll appreciate all the help I can get, thanks.

```
//Main program loop.

void loop( )
{
  float temperature;
  float humidity;

  if( measure_environment( &temperature, &humidity ) == true )
  {
    if (humidity >= 60){
    digitalWrite(pinOut, HIGH);
    }
  else {
    digitalWrite(pinOut, LOW);
     }
    delay(500);

  } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use a boolean to track whether the shower was just active or not, for example like so:

```
boolean shower = false;

.... code

if (humidity >= 60) {
    digitalWrite(pinOut, HIGH);
    shower = true;
} else {
    if (shower) {
        delay(1000 * 60 * 5);
        shower = false;
    }
    digitalWrite(pinOut, LOW);
}

.... code
```

Now, everytime the shower has been turned on, the boolean shower is true. When the humidity drops below 60 again, the boolean is still true and the if-statement nested in the else-statement gets triggered, causing a five minute delay, in which pinOut is still set to high. After that, the boolean gets assigned to false again and the fan gets turned off.